# Regex to Hodorize text

Tags: javascript, regex

Just for jollies, I'm trying to write a regex that replaces every word in `<p>` tags with "hodor", preserving leading capitals, and changing hyphenated words into "ho-dor".

The code I have is:

```
$("p").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text();

    text = text.replace(/\b[A-Z][^\b-]*\b/, "Hodor")
               .replace(/\b[a-z][^\b-]*\b/, "hodor")
               .replace(/\b[A-Z][^\b-]*-[^\b-]+\b/, "Ho-dor")
               .replace(/\b[a-z][^\b-]*-[^\b-]+\b/, "ho-dor")

    $this.text(text);
});
```

Two questions:

1. Can this be done with a single regex rather than four strung-together regexes?
2. This code replaces the entire `<p>` text with single "Hodor"s, rather than each word with a Hodor.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very useful for testing regexes: https://regex101.com/#javascript (there's a substitution option on bottom). You don't stop at word's end as you would expect.

Comment: You should probably take this over to [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) because it's such a goofy question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... `\b` is a zero-width assertion, so it doesn't have any meaning inside of a character class. Replace every instance of `[^\b-]` with `[^\w-]` and it should work.

Then, in order to avoid replacing the strings 4 times, you can use a callback replacement function:

```js
var text = "Hello, world! I am ha-ppy.";

text = text.replace(/\b\w+(-\w+)?/g, function(match, secondWord) {
    var isLowerCase = match[0] == match[0].toLowerCase();

    if (secondWord)
        return isLowerCase ? "ho-dor" : "Ho-dor";
  
    return isLowerCase ? "hodor" : "Hodor";
});

document.write(text); document.close();
```

Comment: I knew that the single regex would use the `function` replacement, but was lazy to try it.